# Out of heap space while building big BasicDBObjects in JRuby

Tags: mongodb, jruby, mongodb-java

i am using JRuby 1.7.0.preview1 for an application. 
This application stores many Documents in Mongodb.

My Problem is, my documents are very big and have a deep structure. 
When i build those documents my java heap is really fast out of space.
(actually i'm using 2GB for Heap Space)

With the memory analyzer i found out that too much of BasicDBObjects exists.

Is there another way to build documents for mongodb in jruby ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Big i terms of near 16MB ? You should avoid that, also deeply nested Structures arent a good idea. You may reconsider your schema design.

Comment: When i avoid deeply nested structures, is it ok, if i save the structures in several collections or in one big one? Which approach is faster?

Comment: faster it terms of what? Depends on the use case. If you want to do just one query, sure a big document is faster than getting multiple documents (network latency). So what is the Use Case and access pattern?